# why does detach thread get no output message?

Tags: c++, multithreading, detach

I am testing a cpp code as below, and got one very confusing phenomena, below code does not print "label" string. Could anyone explain it? really thanks for your help!

```
class Data {
public:
  Data() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  ~Data() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
  void show() { std::cout << label << std::endl; }

private:
  std::string label{"label"};
};

int main() {
  auto data = std::make_shared<Data>();
  std::thread t([=]() mutable{
    data->show();
  });

  t.detach();
}
```

Comment: Nothing prevents your program from exiting before the thread has has any time to run.

Comment: Yes, I know using join() can get the right result, but I just want to understand what hanppened if using detach(), why no output anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comment section by Mat, nothing is preventing the program to end before thread even begins.

Change `t.detach()` to `t.join()`.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) on `join`

> waits for a thread to finish its execution

Comment: Thanks . yes, the reason I used detach() is trying to understand the detach effection. I know I can 
use join() to get the right result.